# Match a HTML form Input with a MD5 SQL password

Tags: html, jstl, md5

I have a html form that goes through JSTL to send the password to check it against the database but the database passwords are in the form MD5. I am not sure how I convert the password submitted to MD5 to try and match it against the password in accounts page.

Comment: You compute the MD5 of the submitted password and see if it matches what you have in the database.

Comment: By the way, you should absolutely NOT use MD5 for production. Use bcrypt or PBKDF2 to store passwords.